# Gitlab HTTPS URI for repository cloning does not work - SSL host could not be verified - fatal: unable to access

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, git, gitlab, eclipse

When I make Eclipse -> File -> Import -> Projects -> Projects from Git -> Clone URI -> enter repository HTTPS URI from Gitlab, I get error:

> Possible reasons:
>   Incorrect URL
>   No network connection (e.g. wrong proxy settings)
>   SSL host could not be verified (set http.sslVerify=false in Git configuration)

I have added `http.sslVerify false` in Eclipse configuration but it still does not work.

If I make `git clone https://my.example.com/gitlab/root/repository.git` in cmd, I get:

> Cloning into 'repository'...
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://my.example.com/gitlab/root/repository.git':   The requested URL returned error: 500

Gitlab production logs show:

> Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as HTML
>     Parameters: {"service"=>"git-upload-pack", "namespace_id"=>"java",   "project_id"=>"project.git"}
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 102ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
>   JWT::DecodeError (Nil JSON web token):
>   lib/gitlab/workhorse.rb:120:in 'verify_api_request!'
>   app/controllers/projects/git_http_client_controller.rb:154:in 'verify_workhorse_api!'
>   lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:15:in 'call'
>   lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'

SSH URL works well. 
Gitlab is used with Apache2 and HTTPS. `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` contains:

> external_url 'https://my.example.com/gitlab'
>   web_server['username'] = 'apache' #'gitlab-www'
>   web_server['group'] = 'apache' #'gitlab-www'
>   nginx['enable'] = false
>   unicorn['listen'] = '127.0.0.1'
>   unicorn['port'] = 9099

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` contains:

> ProxyPass         /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:9099/gitlab
>   ProxyPassReverse  /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:9099/gitlab
>   RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Proto https

Used versions:

> GitLab 8.14.5
>   GitLab Shell 4.0.3
>   GitLab Workhorse 1.1.1
>   GitLab API v3
>   Git  2.7.4

There is article about similar problem [Fixing issues with cloning via HTTPS on GitLab](https://andreas.heigl.org/2016/11/28/fixing-issues-with-cloning-via-https-on-gitlab/) but modifying `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` gitlab-workhorse configuration didn't help.

Similar problems:
[Error 500 on git operation using HTTP(S) with Apache as Reverse Proxy](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23133)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Where exactly did you enter the `http.sslVerify=false` setting?

Comment: In Eclipse IDE -> Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration -> User Settings -> Add entry -> http.sslVerify false

Comment: Assuming Apache >= 2.4.7 the preferred solution is mentioned in the issue the OP already linked: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23133#note_22130175 Also see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/issues/57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabled gitlab-workhorse on 9191 port:

> external_url 'https://my.example.com/gitlab'
>
> gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = true
>   gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
>   gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:9191"
>
> unicorn['listen'] = '127.0.0.1'
>   unicorn['port'] = 9099
>
> web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
>   web_server['username'] = 'apache' #'gitlab-www'
>   web_server['group'] = 'apache' #'gitlab-www'
>
> nginx['enable'] = false

That's the whole gitlab.rb configuration, other lines are commented.

And made `proxyPass` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to the gitlab-workhorse working on 9191 port instead of Unicorn:

> ProxyPass          /gitlab http://127.0.0.1:9191/gitlab
>   RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
>   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on