# Gitlab git clone using HTTPS - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, git, gitlab, eclipse

When I use `git clone https://my.example.com/gitlab/java/repository.git`, I get

> Cloning into 'repository'...
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://my.example.com/gitlab/java/repository.git':
>   SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

It works fine if I set `git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Gitlab is used with Apache2 and SSL which forwards to gitlab-workhorse. More details about configuration: [Gitlab HTTPS URI for repository cloning does not work - SSL host could not be verified - fatal: unable to access](https://serverfault.com/questions/822716/gitlab-https-uri-for-repository-cloning-does-not-work-ssl-host-could-not-be-ve/822971#822971)

I have tried adding SSL certificates as they are the same as in Apache config but it did not help:

> nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/my.example.com.crt"
>   nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/my.example.com.key"

How to configure it to make git actions via HTTPS without disabling verification?

Comment: See https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/9443#issuecomment-120216300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked SSL with https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and it showed some warnings while browser didn't complain about the URL. It was missing `SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt`
in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`.